# How much screen time does Yoda have?

Tags: star-wars

I've managed to convince my young daughter that Yoda is awesome.  She'll hop up into my chair and explain "I want to watch Master Yoda."  I figure, as far as role models go, Yoda's pretty high up there.

Of course, being a fictional role model, his influence is limited.  We only see him so much.  At some point she's going to realize she's just watching the same clips over and over.

How much screen time does Yoda actually have in the Star Wars canon?

Comment: For the record, a canon is a body of works by an author. A cannon is a big metal shooty thing that goes **"Boom!!!"**

Comment: This seems pretty broad. The canon encompasses 13 feature films and *hundreds* of episode of TV shows. Are you wanting the whole thing?

Comment: Well, he's about the same size as my niece and she gets 2 hours on a school day.

Comment: I thought this was gonna be 'how much does Yoda watch TV and use his phone each day'

Answer (score 7):

Overall, Yoda has about 43 minutes and 30 seconds of screentime in the six live-action movies in which he appears (so far), these being Episodes I-III, V-VI, and VIII. This number was calculated by adding up the screentime notes found on IMDB here: https://www.imdb.com/list/ls027631145/ .

Note: This does not include Yoda's screentime in the *Star Wars: The Clone Wars* movie/TV show nor *Star Wars Rebels*. He is a major character in the former, with at least one full episode being dedicated to him.

Comment: Don't forget Lego Star Wars - The Yoda Chronicles.

Comment: That's not part of official canon.

Comment: sadly spacewolf is correct

Comment: Regrettably, neither is "SEAGULLS! (Stop it Now)", although that doesn't prevent my own daughter watching it all the time (she's a bit too young for the movies, I'm convinced she'll be incredibly disappointed to learn the song isn't actually in them).